# Write permutation to text file, keeping only unique permutations

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I would like to write the unique permutations to a text file. I want only the unique version.
My code is as follows:

```
def permute(lst,f=0):
    if f>=len(lst):
        print(lst)
        return
    for s in range(f, len(lst)):
        lst[f],lst[s] = lst[s],lst[f]
        permute(lst,f+1)
        lst[f],lst[s] = lst[s],lst[f]
        
r=permute(['Cat',
'Dog',
'Bird',
'Rabbit'])

f = open("Permutation_File.txt", "w")
f.write(r)
f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Out put looks like this:

```
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Rabbit']
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Bird']
['Cat', 'Bird', 'Dog', 'Rabbit']
['Cat', 'Bird', 'Rabbit', 'Dog']
['Cat', 'Rabbit', 'Bird', 'Dog']
['Cat', 'Rabbit', 'Dog', 'Bird']
['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Rabbit']
['Dog', 'Cat', 'Rabbit', 'Bird']
['Dog', 'Bird', 'Cat', 'Rabbit']
['Dog', 'Bird', 'Rabbit', 'Cat']
['Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Bird', 'Cat']
['Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Cat', 'Bird']
['Bird', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Rabbit']
['Bird', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Cat']
['Bird', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit']
['Bird', 'Cat', 'Rabbit', 'Dog']
['Bird', 'Rabbit', 'Cat', 'Dog']
['Bird', 'Rabbit', 'Dog', 'Cat']
['Rabbit', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Cat']
['Rabbit', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird']
['Rabbit', 'Bird', 'Dog', 'Cat']
['Rabbit', 'Bird', 'Cat', 'Dog']
['Rabbit', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Dog']
['Rabbit', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird']
```

How to go about writing a text file that has only unique permutations?

Would like to see

```
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Bird']
['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Rabbit']
['Bird', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Rabbit']
['Rabbit', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Cat']
```

I know with only 4 strings it's hard to visualize, but I have 36 strings in my set and that comes to well over a million variations.

Comment: The actual list has 36 strings

Comment: what isn't unique about them?

Comment: I am only interested in the first version of the permutation.

Comment: What is the "first version" of the permutation?

Comment: What would you like to see instead in the file in your example?

Comment: [Rabbit, dog, cat, bird] would be the first, the following version where dog, cat, bird are rearranged are irrelevant to my needs.

Comment: you could do it with slicing ```list(itertools.permutations(['Cat',
'Dog',
'Bird',
'Rabbit']))[::6]``` where 6 is from ```(len(['Cat',
'Dog',
'Bird',
'Rabbit'])-1)!``` gives what you want

Comment: @Nin17 Neither of those give the result they say they want. Best just wait for them to clarify what they want. Btw your modulo is pointless.

Comment: In your own words, please describe the logic behind choosing _only_ those arrangements of your list. By definition, all permutations are unique if the elements of your list are unique

Comment: Why do you want `['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Bird']` instead of `['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Rabbit']`?

Comment: @KellyBundy because they'd copied the output incorrectly and that was the first before you edited it

Comment: With 36 strings, you'll have 36! permutations (371993326789901217467999448150835200000000) which on my machine would take ~ 6.648984832621036e+26 years to generate, so generating all permutations is definitely not the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem that you want to generate all permutations at all, you can calculate what you want by just 'rolling' the list:

```
lst =  ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Rabbit']
[lst[i:]+lst[:i] for i, _ in enumerate(lst)]
```

Output:

```
[['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Rabbit'],
 ['Dog', 'Bird', 'Rabbit', 'Cat'],
 ['Bird', 'Rabbit', 'Cat', 'Dog'],
 ['Rabbit', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird']]
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but the `%len(lst)` is unnecessary -- since `i` only varies from `0` to `len(lst)-1`, you have `i == i % len(lst)`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yep edited it, I just copied that from somewhere else